# C# Where to place decimal TryParse

Tags: c#, winforms, parsing, decimal

My program adds selected books to a cart (`cartComboBox`) and then calculates a running total at the bottom (`totalPriceLabel`). I'm having issues with the types, as its pulling in a string and not converting to decimal.

My question is, where is the best place to put a `decimal.TryParse` statement, and if so, does that remove any of the `decimal.Parse` language?

```
private void selectionListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(selectionListBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Visual Basic")
    {
        this.bookPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile("visualbasic.jpg");
        priceLabel.Text = 119.99.ToString("c");
    }
    else if(selectionListBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Java")
    {
        this.bookPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile("java.jpg");
        priceLabel.Text = 109.99.ToString("c");
    }
}

private void addCartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        decimal totalPrice;
        decimal cost = 0;
        // if(decimal.TryParse(priceLabel.Text, out totalPrice)?
        if (cartComboBox.Items.Contains(selectionListBox.SelectedItem))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicates not allowed.");
        }
        else
        {
            //if(decimal.TryParse(priceLabel.Text, out totalPrice)?
            cartComboBox.Items.Add(selectionListBox.SelectedItem);
            totalPrice = decimal.Parse(priceLabel.Text);
            cost += totalPrice;
            totalPriceLabel.Text = cost.ToString("c");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); //input string was not in correct format
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that you are assigning `109.99.ToString("c")` to the label. If you are trying to parse _that_, it's not a valid decimal and won't work.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to parse, to get a running total if the item is added to the cart. I guess that's where I'm misunderstanding how to transfer the price through the add button to get a running total.

Answer (score 0):

I would use it in else statement. I am assuming you only want to add the item if it has a valid price.

```
else
{
    if(decimal.TryParse(priceLabel.Text.Replace("$",""), out totalPrice))
    {
        cartComboBox.Items.Add(selectionListBox.SelectedItem);
        cost += totalPrice;
        totalPriceLabel.Text = cost.ToString("c");
    }
}
```

Comment: Placing it there then doesn't add anything to the combobox. I've nested it under the cartComboBox add, but it doesn't work. And I've placed it as an additional If after the Else closure, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Edited answer to remove $ from textbox.